# C++ diamond interface inheritance

Tags: c++, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have a hierarchy:

```
class ICommand
{
    public:
        virtual void start() = 0;
};

class IExtendedCommand : public ICommand
{
    public:
        virtual void doSomethingElse() = 0;
};

class ConcreteCommand : public ICommand
{
    public:
        virtual void start() {};
}    
class ExtendedConcreteCommand : public ConcreteCommand, public IExtendedCommand
{
    public:
        virtual void doSomethingElse() {};
}
```

ICommand and IExtendedCommand objects are being created by factory.

For some reason when compiler says that all of ICommand's methods are pure within ExtendedConcreteCommand...

Any ideas why and how to solve this?

**PS:** Yes I'm porting my Android app to C++/Qt (which I haven't used for 3 years).
Anyway I'd like to hear how you would cope with this.

**EDIT:**

What I'm porting is a remote control application for MPC and VLC.
The idea is to create commands that can be sent to the player through a factory.
Factory returns a pointer to an object that implements ICommand. So by switching factory implementations different commands can be created. ICommand declares all the main methods and signals. IExtendedCommand adds some generic info across players. So what I'd like to do is instantiate IExtendedCommand through a factory, set some properties and then launch it with start() method. Also I'd like to reuse ConcreteCommand's functionality. That leads to the issue I described.

Comment: this is what happen when you mix Java and C++ :/

Comment: You're going to need to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance .  _Generally_ when you see this, it's a good idea to rethink the design.

Comment: My eyes bleed. That's like looking at Java code with C++ syntax :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a diamond. You have this:

```
   +----------------------------------- missing start() !
   V
pv start()     pv doSomethingElse()     concrete doSomethingElse()

ICommand  ---> IExtendedCommand   ---\
                                      > ExtendedConcreteCommand
ICommand  ---> ConcreteCommand    ---/

pv start()     concrete start()
```

That means that you have **two** base classes of type `ICommand`, and you need to override both their pure methods. But only `ConcreteCommand` overrides the "bottom" version of `start`, and the other one remains unoverridden.

If you want an actual diamond, you need to make the `ICommand` base class *virtual* by using virtual inheritance: `class IExtendedCommand : virtual public ICommand`, and likewise for `ConcreteCommand`. Alternatively, you can provide another overrider for `start` in `ExtendedConcreteCommand`.

Comment: Implementing start in ExtendedConcreteCommand like this start() { ConcreteCommand::start(); } worked. But is it ok to do this? And another thing - when I try to return ExtendedConcreteCommand from a factory method that returns ICommand I get ambiguity compile error.

Comment: @KostiaDombrovsky: Whether it's OK depends on what your design requirements are! Do you understand how the inheritance works, and what the difference between virtual and non-virtual inheritance is? Only you can make that decision. Feel free to elaborate on your needs in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your notation, `ExtendedConcreteCommand` is supposed to be a concrete class, which means that somewhere you tried to do

```
ExtendedConcreteCommand command;
```

In the code you uploaded though, `ExtendedConcreteCommand` is a pure virtual class because the method `IExtendedCommand::start()` is pure virtual.

Actually, diamond inheritance is poor coding practice and **should be avoided**. If you insist in doing this, to avoid having compiler issues you have to define `IExtendedCommand::start()`. By modifying your class to

```
class IExtendedCommand : public ICommand
{
    public:
        virtual void doSomethingElse() = 0;
        virtual void start() {};
};
```

your code compiles.

You can also use `virtual` inheritance. In that case you will have **only one instance of** `ICommand`, and a real diamond. In your example, you have **two** instances of `ICommand`: one coming from `IExtendedCommand` and another coming from `ConcreteCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

Just inherit `virtual`ly from the interface.

That does have a runtime cost.